# NPM installation issue ubuntu

Tags: angularjs, laravel, npm

I want to install npm for use angular2 with laravel5.2 , but while installation of npm. I got below issue :

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v0.10.25
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:298
        [this, (next) => { computeMetadata(this.idealTree); next() }],
                       ^
npm ERR! Unexpected token >  

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
npm ERR!     /home/swapnily/.npm/_logs/2017-07-06T07_21_24_104Z-debug.log
```

Please let me know if anyone aware about same.

Comment: The first 3 lines says you everything.

Comment: @BelminBedak,  I have install "
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs "                                                                                 but even i get above error.

Comment: If you type `node -v` in terminal what you get ?

Comment: @BelminBedak, v0.10.25

Comment: That version is several years old - go here and download & install it https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Double check there is no error during install.

Then restart you ssh session (just in case) by typing `exit` then re-connect.

Then check your install with `node -v`.

If it still does not work, you should check which `node` is used with `which node`. The problem may be here (an old version of node is installed somewhere else and in use).

Comment: it's showing same version. means no version upgrade

Answer (score 0):

> npm does not support Node.js v0.10.25

You're using `v0.10.25` which was long deprecated hence this error.

> You need node v4 or higher to run this program.
>
> To install an old and unsupported version of npm that works on node v0.12 and prior, clone the git repo and dig through the old tags and branches.

Source [npm's doc](https://github.com/npm/npm#important)

> I have install " curl -sL deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x

It isn't clear whether this succeed or not. Assuming that this succeed without errors. Check which version of node is currently being used.

```
sridharrajs@debian:~$ which node  
/home/sridharrajs/.nvm/versions/node/v5.11.1/bin/node  -- In mycase I'm using version 5.11.1
```

Switch to `v6.x.x` which you've just installed and retry installing.

If you still had issues in installing and switching node versions I recommend you to check
[nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Using this you can  install and switch versions easily.

Comment: swapnily@swapnily:~/Downloads$ which node
/usr/bin/node

Comment: @SwapnilYeole I think v6.x installation failed because it doesn't show up in `which node`. Try installing by alternate method using `nvm` and switch to the recent version.